# PHP Trying to add ability to send attachment to working contact us form

Tags: php, email, attachment, email-attachments

I have a friend who asked me to modify her website's contact form to request phone number and also the ability to add photo attachments. I've added the code necessary to request and send the phone number with the email, but adding the ability to attach photo files is beyond the current scope of my knowledge. Could someone take a look at the code and tell me how to add the ability to attach files to the message? All I'm trying to do is add this below the current message field, but it's proving to be more involved than I expected. Since everything I tried has broken the current form, I've removed my code attempts to add the attachment and I'm posting the code as it currently works. It's my hope someone with a better grasp of php can help us with this.

```
    <?php
      //set the level of error reporting
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);  

      // Set-up these 3 parameters
      $to = 'any@somewhere.net';
      $subject = 'Question from The website';
      $contact_submitted = 'Your message has been sent.';

      function email_is_valid($email) {
        return preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i',$email);
      }
      if (!email_is_valid($to)) {
        echo '<p style="color: red;">You must set-up a valid (to) email address before this contact page will work.</p>';
      }
      if (isset($_POST['contact_submitted'])) {
        $return = "\n\r";
        $youremail = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['your_email']));
        $yourname = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['your_name']));
        $yourphone = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['your_phone']));
        $yourmessage = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['your_message']));
        $contact_name = "Name: ".$yourname;
        $contact_email = "Email Address: ".$youremail;
        $contact_phone = "Phone: ".$yourphone;
        $message_text = "Message: ".$yourmessage;
        $user_answer = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_answer']));
        $answer = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['answer']));
        $message = $contact_name . $return . $contact_email . $return . $contact_phone . $return . $return . $message_text;
        $headers = "From: ".$youremail;
        if (email_is_valid($youremail) && !eregi("\r",$youremail) && !eregi("\n",$youremail) && $yourname != "" && $yourphone != "" && $yourmessage != "" && substr(md5($user_answer),5,10) === $answer) {
          mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
          $yourname = '';
          $youremail = '';
          $yourphone = '';
          $yourmessage = '';
          echo '<p style="color: blue;">'.$contact_submitted.'</p>';
        }
        else echo '<p style="color: red;">Please enter your name, a valid email address, your message and the answer to the simple maths question before sending your message.</p>';
      }
      $number_1 = rand(1, 9);
      $number_2 = rand(1, 9);
      $answer = substr(md5($number_1+$number_2),5,10);
    ?>
    <form id="contact" action="contact.php" method="post">
      <div class="form_settings">
        <p><span>Name:</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_name" value="<?php $yourname; ?>" /></p>
        <p><span>Email Address:</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_email" value="<?php $youremail; ?>" /></p>
        <p><span>Phone Number:</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_phone" value="<?php $yourphone; ?>" /></p>
        <p><span>Message:</span><textarea class="contact textarea" rows="1" cols="50" name="your_message"><?php $yourmessage; ?></textarea></p>
        <p style="line-height: 1.7em;">To help prevent spam, please enter the answer to this question:</p>
        <p><span><?php echo $number_1; ?> + <?php echo $number_2; ?> = ?</span><input type="text" name="user_answer" /><input type="hidden" name="answer" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>" /></p>
        <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="submit" type="submit" name="contact_submitted" value="send" /></p>
      </div>
    </form>
```

If anyone can figure this out I'd be forever grateful.

Comment: There are easier ways of getting laid :)

Comment: Consider using PHPMailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Answer (score 1):

First problem you're going to have is that you're not going to be able to upload any file without indicating the

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

within the form tag.

The rest of the info, you could refer to this [tutorial](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html)